# Copy text to clipboard using JavaScript / PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Trying to make a link that will copy some text, and what I was wondering (I have read some articles but they were for when people input things) if there was a way to just put any random text into the clipboard? I wanted to do this using JavaScript to do the actual copying and use PHP to get the actual data that I want to copy, I dont know that much JavaScript so keep that in mind, Thanks.

Comment: Nothing will beat Zero Clipboard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432838/how-to-install-zeroclipboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recurrent question and it is a lot of "solutions" but mostly you will end up using flash if you want full platform support.

If that is not the case, you can use libraries like [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/), and there's a lot more out there, just look for them.

Comment: Flash itself doesn't exactly full platform support.

Comment: True, but sadly is the "most complete" solution we have so far

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="copy-text">Some Text</div>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#copy-text')" type="button" >Copy</button>
```

JS

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
```